# Python: What is the point of using "import"?

Tags: python, modules, class

I am not very clear on this aspect. Let's say you have a bunch of .py files that are their own separate modules.

Why does each .py file need to import the others when they use that class? Or do they? Because I was pretty sure that other languages (Java, for instance), did not require import when referring to classes/files in the same directory. I might be wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Simply put, that is the way it was designed. You mentioned Java as a counter example - the Java language designers wanted to make classloading somewhat implicit, so they check the same directory before throwing `ClassNotFound`. Outside of that you need to qualify, just like in Python.

As Tom Anderson said, C does the same thing as Python, and it's a compiled language. Perhaps the interpreted nature of the language had something to do with the final decision (for performance, explicitness, etc.), but in the end it's up to the developer.

Comment: I'm not sure that, "that is the way it was designed" is really answer to this question.

Comment: -1: I don't know Python well, but my understanding is that you _have_ to import a package to use anything in it in Python.  In Java, you don't technically ever have to use import statements; you could just write out the full, qualified names of classes, etc. in other packages.

Comment: Qualification is resolving the path to an object (class, function, whatever). Whether it is done by imports or syntax qualifiers is irrelevant.

Answer (score 3):

Because python is interpreted everything you import is available at the prompt.
Java (and C++) have a compile and link step which can search out and include only functions that are used

If everything was automatically imported there would be 1000s of functions and variables and it would be impossible to type anything without colliding with one.

edit: Ok it's a little more than just compiled vs interpreted. Python is intended as a "batteries included" language - there are libraries available to do almost everything. Since you are only ever going to use a small fraction of those there needs to be a way of organising them so that you only include those you need.

The import from syntax is clever because you can either import the whole library and keep Java-like fully qualified names or you can import specific functions (or all functions) into the local namespace

```
>>>import math
>>> math.sin(0)  #no confusion with any other 'sin'

>>> from math import sin  # or import *
>>> sin(0) # makes equations with sin shorter and simpler
```

The second reason is is especially important in a dynamic language like python. Since you don't have to define variables before you use them it would be difficult for the environment to work out if `sin` is the maths function or a variable of yours in an interpreter.

Comment: I don't get it... Could you explain it for a newb? :(

Comment: @ChuckTesta To fully understand the difference discusssed in this answer, you need to understand the difference between compiled and interpreted languages - this blog post sums it up in quite simple terms: http://blog.julipedia.org/2004/07/compiled-vs-interpreted-languages.html

Comment: The difference has absolutely nothing to do with interpreted vs compiled. You could write a Python compiler and would have to work exactly the same way as the Python interpreter. The difference is simply that the designers of Java (say) decided to add implicit loading of classes from other files, and the designer(s) of Python didn't. Note that C is compiled, but has essentially the same rules as Python - you can't use a function from another file unless you #include a header for it and link the right library.

Comment: The point is valid: implicit class loading would have a big runtime cost in an interpreted language

Comment: I agree with Tom Anderson on this one. It was simply an implementation choice. I also agree with @Simon as to why it was a justified choice. Can't +1 this because I feel its a truth but not thoroughly explained yet. Spruce it up to include some more in depth justification and you have my vote.

Comment: @Tom - yes it's really more that a compiler/linker has more ability to determine use and scope - I just couldn't think of a simple way to describe that to a beginner.

Comment: @Simon, why would it have a big runtime cost?

Comment: -1: You can have packages in a language without requiring include statements.  Python could have been designed so that you never _have_ to use import statements; libraries could just be loaded when an identifier in another package is used for the first time (though that might be a little less efficient overall).

Comment: @compman - yes but thats the problem with a language that includes so many libs. You would either have to think of 1000 synonyms for `load` or have to enter `os.network.web.html5.load()` as opposed to `multimedia.video.avi.h264.load()` - the `import` and `import from` lets you have these multiple uses and yet keep the names simple

Answer (score 1):

Imagine you had this code in python:

```
foo = MyObject()
fo.bar()
```

Obviously, we've got a typo and `fo` should have been `foo`. Right now python says:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'fo' is not defined
```

But with implicit class loading it might say:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named fo
```

which would be confusing. Worse yet, if you misspelled a variable name that just happened to be the name of a module, you would get an even more confusing error as you tried to treat that module as if it were your variable. Python can't tell whether something is a class name, object or whatever.

Java, on the other hand, I believe can tell from the syntax whether a certain identifier refers to a class or something else. Thus it has no problem with producing an appropriate error message.

Overall, it fits into the Python philosophy of being explicit rather then implicit. They figure its better to explicitly import a module rather than have it imported automatically. The error message issue is factor that plays into the decision.

Some have suggested that there would be a large runtime cost to implicit imports. I don't think so. What happens is something like this:

1. LOAD_GLOBAL opcode invoked with name "foo"
2. globals dictionary checked for "foo"
3. **builtins** dictionary checked for "foo"
4. If foo found, store in globals and continue on
5. If foo not found, raise NameError

To support implicit module loading we could do:

1. LOAD_GLOBAL opcode invoked with name "foo"
2. globals dictionary checked for "foo"
3. **builtins** dictionary checked for "foo"
4. if the above fail, try `import foo`
5. If foo found, store in globals and continue on
6. If foo not found, raise NameError

The first time the module is used, it would take a bit longer because it has to search through other dictionaries first. But that's only the first time, and shouldn't be significant in terms of whole program runtime.

There would be a significant cost, in the case of misspelled variable names. When they occour, python would waste time reading the disk trying to find the module. But if that happens your program is about to die with a traceback anyways and the performance isn't a big concern.

Answer (score 1):

There are some important differences between Python and Java; while Java has a "one class per file" rule, Python does not.  Also, not everything in Python is a class.

So a module can have classes, functions, and just plain old variables -- usually all related in some way (such as random functions in `random`, math routines in `math`, string contstants in `string`, etc).

If you want to access any of classes/function/variables from a particular module, you must first import it.

Why is this a Good Thing?

- Keeps module name spaces clean (not cluttered with names you will never use)
- Easier to track back to the appropriate module when something goes wrong
- Allows you to use names without fear of either an error because the name is in use, or clobbering the already in-use name (you can have `math.sin` and your own `sin` functions)
- Helps clarify program structure.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most important concepts in Python is that of namespaces (do `import this` at the prompt some time to find out what the others are). I know that namespaces exist in other languages too, but in Python you only have access to the current namespace, which is what's defined in the current module. To get access to other identifiers, you need to import them into the current namespace: either by importing their containing module (the `import foo` syntax) or the names themselves (`from foo import bar`).